# Vim scroll setting overridden

Tags: vim

I am trying to apply the following setting for my `.tex` files:

```
set scroll=4
```

I've put this both in my `~/.vimrc` and in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` file.
For general files, this works fine. For `.tex` files, all other settings in these files are applied. But not the scroll setting.

Note: I have latex-suite installed, which is what I suspect is overriding the setting.

When I type

```
:verbose set scroll
```

I get:

```
  scroll=22
    Last set from ~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim
```

Note: 22 is half the height (number of lines) of the gvim window.

If I source the `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` file while editing, the scroll setting is applied fine, but I want it to be applied along with the other settings at startup.

Thanks

### Update:

Thanks for the good advice. It didn't work yet though. I looked at `scriptnames` and here's the output:

```
    62: /home/patrick/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim
    63: /home/patrick/.vim/indent/tex.vim
    64: /usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/bib.vim
    65: /home/patrick/.vim/ftplugin/bib_latexSuite.vim
    66: /home/patrick/.vim/after/ftplugin/bib.vim
    67: /usr/share/vim/vim72/indent/bib.vim
    68: /home/patrick/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
    69: /home/patrick/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
```

As you can see, I also added a bib.vim file in the `after/ftplugin` directory, because I'm loading 4 tabs at startup, one of which is a bib file.
However, it still doesn't work.

### Update 2

Well I still got the same problem, but with more information. I'm now running a Windows build of vim. Again vim claims scroll was last set in `~/.vimrc`. But this gets overridden whenever

- I open a new tab (with any old file, so the vimrc setting should
  still apply)
- I resize the gvim window

Hence I no longer believe this has anything to do with latex-suite or the order in which the settings are called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a fix/hack. It probably hasn't got anything to do with latex suite or all that. It is overridden when a new tab is opened or the window is resized. A quick fix is to use

```
noremap <C-u> 4<C-u>
```

Which consequently is always used when scrolling. This also sets the `scroll` variable to 4, so it will apply to  as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `tex.vim` in your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` directory. See `:help after` for the details.

Also see the output of `:scriptnames` to check the order in which vim loads all the script files.

Comment: Thanks, although it didn't work yet. See updated edit please.

Answer (score 1):

Patricks remap answer definitely works. Another option for this being reset every time vim is resized would be to use another `autocmd`

```
  autocmd VimResized * :set scroll=10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType tex setlocal scroll=4
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the scroll setting was overridden by the `:set laststatus=2` command.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2010 17:51:38)
```

Even if I add `:set scroll=4` before or after `:set laststatus=2` in .vimrc, `scroll=4` is still overridden.




If I manually reload the .vimrc file with:

```
:so ~\.vimrc
```

Then the scroll setting works.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the solution is to have the `scroll` configured to the desired value in your `~/.vimrc`.  Though, the trouble with using `set scroll=n` is that the value becomes reset to `0` whenever the current window size changes, for example when opening the built-in help using `:h scroll`, or when browsing the search history using `q/`.

To preserve the `scroll` setting across all windows and after all window size changes, I've implemented this vimscript code in my `~/.vimrc`, which keeps the cursor position unchanged while scrolling using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. Of course, you can adjust this code easily to suit your needs, just change `=1` to `=4`, for example:

```
set scroll=1
function! PreserveScroll(timer)
  set scroll=1
endfunction
augroup vimrc-preserve-scroll
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimResized * set scroll=1
  autocmd WinEnter   * set scroll=1
  autocmd WinLeave   * call timer_start(300, "PreserveScroll", {"repeat": 3})
augroup END
```

Obviously, setting up a timer isn't the best solution, but unfortunately I see no better way to have `set scroll=n` executed upon returning to a window, for example after closing the help window.